# Downloading all records of a paginated resource in ActiveAdmin

Tags: activeadmin

I am trying to use the collection action "download_csv" already present in Active Admin to download all the records of a resource. However, the action only downloads the contents of the present page. As I have paginated the resource, the data needs to be downloaded from all the pages. Any suggestions on how I can approach this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer might be a little late but hopefully it can help somebody.

Here is how I have this working in my current app:

```
csv do
  ModelName::ATTR_ADMIN_EXPORT.each do |sym|
    column sym
  end
end
```

And in the model I have ATTR_ADMIN_EXPORT defined like this:

```
ATTR_ADMIN_EXPORT = [:name, :created_at]
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Answer (score 5):

Just for future googlers. My fix (working for the current Master 1.0.0pre) is to add the following to `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class ResourceController
    module DataAccess
      # needed for current active admin master
      def max_per_page
        30_000
      end

      def per_page
        return 30_000 if %w(text/csv application/xml application/json).include?(request.format)

        return max_per_page if active_admin_config.paginate == false

        @per_page || active_admin_config.per_page
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Replace the max as needed. This works for csv, xml and json downloads.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
before_filter :only => :index do
  @per_page = 10 unless request.format == 'text/csv'
end
```

This code will also make the pagination dynamic.

```
 before_filter :only => :index do
   if params[:pag].blank?
     @per_page = AdminSetting.where(:name => 'JobPagination').first.value.to_i unless request.format == 'text/csv'
   else
     @per_page = 10  
   end
 end
```